# Status bar overlapping with activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout

**Problem**

[image]

Status bar overlapping with Toolbar. I have tried to setting various attributes but it isn't working out. So now suggest me what to do with this issue and what is causing this issue.
One more thing to note is that I've used transparent status bar attribute in one other activity.

**activity_symptom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor.SymptomActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_symptom" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_symptom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor.SymptomActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_symptom">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/symptom1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Symptom 1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:paddingStart="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/symptom2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Symptom 2" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:paddingStart="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/symptom3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Symptom 3" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:paddingStart="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="70dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="127dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="170dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="19">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="21">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/indigo</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/pink</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
    <item name="android:padding">20dp</item>
</style>

//Styles for Trending Topics Content Header Text

<style name="TextAppearance.Design.CollapsingToolbar.Expanded.Shadow">
    <item name="android:shadowDy">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">8</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeNavigation" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="19">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="21">true</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: try adding `<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>` to your main AppTheme style

Comment: Not Working....

Comment: maybe try increasing the height of the toolbar by adding whatever height the status bar is?